# Observable fired twice when firebase ref ordered by timestamp

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat, ionic3

I am making a chat app using firebase. I added an observable when there are new message to the chat. The prb I have is that the messages are shown twice when I order the messages by timestamp, even though the save message functionality runs on time only.
Here is the observable:

```
return new Observable((observer) => {
  var result = [];
  var lastMessage;
  var order = 'msgId';
  this.db.ref('/chats/' + channelId + '/messages').orderByChild(order).startAt(lastMsgId)
   .once('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      result.push(childSnapshot.val())
      return true;
    })
    if(result.length)
      lastMsgId = result[result.length-1].msgId + 1;
      observer.next(result);
    })
})
```

Save to database function:

```
saveMessageToDatabase(currentUserId, otherUserId, channelId, message) {
    messageObj = {
      key: channelId,
      msgId: lastActivity,
      message: message,
      uid: currentUserId,
      timestamp: lastActivity
    };
  this.db.ref('/chats/' + channelId + '/messages/').push(messageObj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you service(recommended)/component:

```
constructor(private angularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

// lastMsgId: number | string
OnGetMessages(channelId: string, order: string, lastMsgId: number){
    return this.angularFireDatabase
      .list(`/chats/${channelId}/messages `, 
      ref => ref.orderByChild(order).startAt(lastMsgId))
      .valueChanges();
}
```

In your component:

```
myMessages: any
//if you used service you should provide it in constructor.
constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

ngOnInit(){
  // you can esle where in other function, ngOnInit used just for example.
  this.firebaseService.subscribe((msgs)=>{
      console.log(msgs);
      this.myMessages = msgs;
    })
}
```

Let me know if it was helpful. Good luck with coding.